# Java heap size usage

Tags: java, heap-memory

I've written a simple application that works with database. My program have a table to show data from database. When I try to expand frame the program fails with OutOfMemory error, but if i don't try to do this, it works well.

I start my program with -Xmx4m parametre. Does it really need more than 4 megabytes to be in expanded state?

Another question: if I run the java visualVM I see the saw-edged chart of the heap usage of my program while other programs which is using java VM(such as netbeans) have more rectilinear charts. Why is heap usage of my program so unstable even if it does nothing(only waiting for user to push a button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try setting this value to generate a detailed heap dump to show you exactly what is going on.

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

A typical "small" Java desktop application in 2011 is going to run with ~64-128MB.  Unless you have a really pressing need, I would start by leaving it set to the default (i.e. no setting).

If you are trying to do something different (e.g. run this on an Android device), you are going to need to get very comfortable with profiling (and you should probably post with that tag).

Keep in mind that your 100 record cache (~12 bytes) may (probably) is double that if you are storing character data (Java uses UCS-16 internally).

RE: the "unstability", the JVM is going handling memory usage for you, and will perform garbage collection according to whatever algos it chooses (these have changed dramatically over the years).  The graphing may just be an artifact of the tool and the sample period.  The performance in a desktop app is affected by a *huge* number of factors.

As an example, we once had a huge memory "leak" that only showed up in one automated test but never showed up in normal real world usage.  Turned out the test left the mouse hovering over a tool tip which included the name of the open file, which in turn had a set of references back to the entire (huge) project.  Wiggling the mouse a few pixels got rid of the tooltip, which meant that the references all cleared up and the garbage collector took out the trash.

Moral of the story?  You need to capture the exact heap dump at time of the out-of-memory and review it very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you set your maximum heap size to 4 megabytes? Java is often memory intensive, so setting it at such a ridiculously low level is a recipe for disaster.

It also depends on how many objects are being created and destroyed by your code, and the underlying Swing (I am assuming) components use components to draw the elements, and how these elements are created and destroyed each time a components is redrawn.
Look at the CellRenderer code and this will show you why objects are being created and destroyed often, and why the garbage collector does such a wonderful job.

Try playing with the Xmx setting and see how the charts flatten out. I would expect Xmx64m or Xmx128m would be suitable (although the amount of data coming out of your database will obviously be an important contributing factor.

Comment: I use a cashe of 100 records(each record is of 12 bytes about) to get the data from database, so it always use constant amount of memory to store data from db

Answer (score 1):

You may need more than 4Mb for a GUI with an expanded screen if you are using a double buffer. This will generate multiple image of the UI. It does this to show them quickly on the screen. Usually this is done assuming you have lots and lots of memory.

The Sawtooth memory allocation is due to something being done, then garbage collected. This may be on a repaint operation or other timer. Is there a timer in your code to check some process or value being changed. Or have you added code to a object repaint or other process?

Answer (score 0):

I think 4mb is too small for anything except a trivial program - for example lots of GUI libraries (Swing included) will need to allocate temporary working space for graphics that alone may exceed that amount.

If you want to avoid out of memory errors but also want to avoid over-allocating memory to the JVM, I'd recommend setting a **large maximum heap** size and a **small initial heap size**.

- Xmx (the maximum heap size) should
  generally be quite large, e.g. 256mb
- Xms (the initial heap size) can be
  much smaller, 4mb should work -
  though remember that if the application needs more
  than this there will be a temporary performance
  hit while it is resized